# Understanding character sets in column and data and how they affect select queries

Tags: mysql

After reading articles about how to properly store your data inside a mysql database, I sort of have a good understanding of how character sets work. Yet, there are still some instances that I find hard to understand. Let me give a quick example: Say I have a table with a varchar column using the latin1 charset (for example purposes)

```
CREATE TABLE `foobar` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and I force insert a latin1 character using its hex value (á for instance, which would be E1)

```
SET NAMES 'latin1';
INSERT INTO foobar SET foo = UNHEX('E1')
```

why does a SELECT query against this table under a latin1 connection fail to give me the value I am expecting? I get the replacement character instead. I would have expected it to just give back the value as it is since the column was in latin1, the connection itself was in latin1 and the value stored is a valid latin1 character. Is mysql trying to interpret E1 as a UTF8 value? Or am I missing something here?

Using a UTF8 connection (SET NAMES 'utf8') before selecting gives me the expected value of á, which I guess is correct since from what I understand, if the connection charset is different from the column charset being selected, then mysql would read data as whatever the column charset was (so E1 gets parsed as a latin1 character, or á)

Comment: Which version of MySQL, and which operating system?

Comment: Was testing this with 5.7.11, on ubuntu 14.04.4